# Pregunta sobre el uso de TreeSet e Iteradores en JAVA

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, iteradores

Tengo una pregunta con respecto el tema de TreeSets e Iteradores, Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public static Alumno mejorPromedio(TreeSet<Alumno> alumnos, String carrera) {


        TreeSet<Alumno> alu = new TreeSet<Alumno>();
        Iterator<Alumno> aluiter = alu.iterator();
        Alumno al = aluiter.next();
        double mayor = al.getPromedio();
        while(aluiter.hasNext()) {

        }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que lea un archivo de texto con informacion de alumnos con el siguiente formato:
    Nombre: Marlin      Apellido: Fish      Matricula: A0998866 Promedio: 65.0  Carrera: ISC

Y en este caso el método me regrese el alumno con mejor promedio de cada carrera, he intentado cosas como: return al.getPromedio(); fuera del while pero me marca el error "cannot convert double to alumno", entiendo cual es el problema pero no entiendo cual es la forma de resolverlo, no se cual es la forma de regresar un alumno.

Como información extra el esqueleto de mi clase alumno es la siguiente:

```
public Alumno(String nombre, String apellido, double promedio, String matricula, String carrera)
```

Con sus setters y getters correspondientes.Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

`next` es para avanzar a la siguiente posición del iterador y te devuelve el elemento. 
`hasNext` verifica si aún hay mas elementos. Por eso no te funciona, primero debes preguntar si hay mas elementos y luego lo extraes, y tu lo tienes al revés.
Intenta algo así

```
TreeSet<Alumno> alu = new TreeSet<Alumno>();
Iterator<Alumno> aluiter = alu.iterator();
double mayor=0.0;
Alumno alumnoTemp=null;
while(aluiter.hasNext()) {
    Alumno al = aluiter.next();
    double temp = al.getPromedio();
    if(temp>mayor){
       mayor=temp;
       alumnoTemp=al;
    }
}
System.out.println(alumnoTemp);
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, tratare de aplicar eso y lo revisare.